# Modular Inverses Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the smallest positive integer $a$ such that $a^{-1}$ is undefined $\pmod{55}$ and $a^{-1}$ is also undefined $\pmod{66}$?

---

How do I solve this problem?  Modular inverses is new to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: An inverse of $a$ modulo $n$ exists iff $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

---

One way to prove this hint is to make use of [Bézout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) connected directly to the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) stating that there exist $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that:
$$
ax+ny=\gcd(a,n)
$$
an then note that for any $x',y'\in\mathbb Z$ we know that $\gcd(a,n)$ almost by definition divides the expression:
$$
ax'+ny'
$$
since it divides $a$ and $n$. Thus the equation
$$
ax'+ny'=1
$$
has a solution if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, which in turn is equivalent to showing the existence of the inverse $a^{-1}=x'$.

Comment: Why isn't the answer 11, then?

Comment: @Regina: Indeed it is!

Answer (score 1):

A modular inverse is not defined if it isn't relatively prime to the modulus. In this case, 11 is not relatively prime to 55 or 66, so it's a value that works. However, the factors of 55 are 11 and 5, and factors of 66 are 2, 3, and 11. If a = 10, which has a factorization of 2 * 5, then it's the smallest possible value of a that works, not 11.